# Non-vanishing Jacobian determinant is bounded below?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ ($m < n$) be a Lipschitz function whose Jacobian determinant $J F$ does not vanish on a compact set $A \subseteq  \mathbb{R^n}$. Assume $J F$ exists everywhere.

Does this imply $J F(x)$ is bounded away from zero for all $x \in A$?

I know this would follow from $x \mapsto J F (x)$ being a continuous map or even a closed map, but I don't see why either of those should be true.

The Jacobian determinant of $F$ is defined as $$J F(x) = \sqrt{ \text{det}( DF(x) DF(x)^T )  },$$ 
where $D F$ is the $m \times n$ matrix of partial derivatives  of $F$.

Comment: Does $|\cdot|$ signify a norm?

Comment: Just absolute value. I suppose it is superfluous. I'll edit

Comment: @ChristianBlatter You wrote correct in parentheses. Did you do that because the claim (properly formulated) is correct?

Comment: Do you mean $JF$ exists everywhere? So this is in the setting of "pointwise differentiability", an unnatural function class. There are counterexamples with $n=m=1.$

Comment: @Dap Yes, I think that should be assumed. I have written it explicitly now. There are indeed counterexamples when $n=m=1$. I am asking about $1 \leq m < n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a counterexample with $n=m=1,$ and compose with a projection to get a map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ satisfying the requriements.